# How to mantain a position from a local variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, im getting this error "Variable doesn't exist in current context?" line(30, 12), which doesn't matter too much, i just want to know how can i mantain the position that my "for" have and put in a variable. I need this because i'm trying to do and "Id" check as you can see in the code (Just look for the idImagem part). Is there a way to do that?
By the way, here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class RandomizarCartas : MonoBehaviour {

public Sprite[] _meusOutrosSprites;
private Image[] _images;
private int idImagem;
private int numeroSpriteInt;

public void Start()
{         
 _images = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
 StartCoroutine(Count());      
}

IEnumerator Count()
{                      
     for(int i = 0; i < _images.Length; i++)
     {
           var numeroSprite = Random.Range(0, _meusOutrosSprites.Length - 1);
          _images[i].sprite = _meusOutrosSprites[numeroSprite];
     }

     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
}
public void PegarID(){
  switch (numeroSprite){
      case 0:
        idImagem=1;
        break;
      case 1:
        idImagem=2;
        break;
      case 2:
        idImagem=3;
        break;
      case 3:
        idImagem=4;
        break;
      case 4:
        idImagem=5;
        break;
      default:
      break;

  }
public void LetraA(){
  if(idImagem==1){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
  }else{
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
  }
}

public void LetraB(){
  if(idImagem==2){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
  }else{
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
  }
}

public void LetraC(){
  if(idImagem==3){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
  }else{
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
  }
}

public void LetraD(){
  if(idImagem==4){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
  }else{
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
  }
}

public void LetraE(){
  if(idImagem==5){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
  }else{
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
  }
}

public void LetraF(){
  if(idImagem==6){
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Sucesso");
  }else{
      SceneManager.LoadScene("Fases");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `im getting this error,` What exact error, on what exact line?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `idImagem==1;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140583/variable-doesnt-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: **1.** `private int numeroSpriteInt;` should be `private int numeroSprite` since that's what you're using in your `switch (numeroSprite)` code. Not sure why you have "Int" at the end of it. **2.** You assign value to variables with **one** `=` not two. So, replace your `idImagem == 1;  `with `idImagem = 1;`. Do that for the rest of the `case` code. **3**. I suggest you start with some [C# tutorial for beginners](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting).

Comment: Your `PegarID` doesn't do anything, (nor is it being called) but maybe you should be passing `numeroSprite` as a parameter?

Comment: First answer is for "mjwills"
1.When i say "this error", i mean by the title
2.I came from Javascript to C#, in that language is like that, it is just me being a noob basically, sorry...
3.Nooooope, is not, i read this article before and it didn't helped me
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Second answer goes to "Programmer"
1. The Variable `private int numeroSpriteInt` was made for that, my original plan was making numeroSprite=numeroSpriteInt, but it didn't worked aaaand i want to keep the positions that are inside the var (created in the `IEnumerator Count()` for, in a variable, but i couldn't manage to do this yet.
2.Ops, sorry, i came from JavaScript and there is like that, gonna correct this right away.
3. Truth hurts ;-;
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Third answer goes to "Draco18s"
Would it mantain the position that it got from the for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numeroSprite` is declared as local variable inside of `IEnumerator Count()`. It doesn't exist outside of that method. If you want to be able to access it in another method make it a private variable:

```
private int numeroSprite;

private IEnumerator Count()
{                      
     for(int i = 0; i < _images.Length; i++)
     {
           var numeroSprite = Random.Range(0, _meusOutrosSprites.Length - 1);
          _images[i].sprite = _meusOutrosSprites[numeroSprite];
     }

     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
}

public void PegarID(){
  switch (numeroSprite){

  // ...
```

or use the `numeroSpriteInt` you already declared but never used just the same way.

```
private int numeroSpriteInt;

private IEnumerator Count()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _images.Length; i++)
    {
        numeroSpriteInt = Random.Range(0, _meusOutrosSprites.Length - 1);
        _images[i].sprite = _meusOutrosSprites[numeroSprite];
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
}

public void PegarID(){
  switch (numeroSpriteInt){

  // ...
```

---

As Programmer already sayd in your `case`s you rather want to do

```
idImage = XY;
```

Instead of your whole switch thing to me it looks way more reasonable to just use something like

```
if(numeroSprite >=0 && numeroSprite <=10)
{
    idImage = numeroSprite + 1;
}
```

Comment: Wuuuuut, it was that easy? i feel like and idiot now...
And by the way, that `idImagem` solution is nice, really, buuuut in my case it's not working cause the idImagem number doesn't seem to be correct, thanks for all the help!